# Emma android get runtime coverage data

Tags: java, android, emma

during android application test, is possibile to access emma coverage data? in the documentation is written emma write coverage (coverage.ec) and metadata (coverage.em) files at the end of the test, but is possible to access data while test is running? Thank's